# $exception {"unexpected token 'creator'"} Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException

Tags: c#, python

I have a **`C#`** application through which I want to run a python script. What python script does is it takes a doc files and create other 3 doc files.

I'm getting an error from this code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace Project_new
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button Welcome = new Button();
            Welcome.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(Welcome_Click);
            ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)(sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem;
        }

        private void Welcome_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            var ComboItem = new1.SelectedValue;// Item;// (ComboBoxItem)cmbDeviceDefinitionId.SelectedItem;
             string s = ((System.Windows.FrameworkElement)ComboItem).Name;
            //string name = ComboItem. Name;
            if (new1.SelectedValue == cbi1)
                {
                Window1 win1 = new Window1();
                win1.Show();
                this.Close();

                // python script to be loaded
                    var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();
                    string importScript = "import sys" + Environment.NewLine + "sys.path.append(r\"{0}\")" + Environment.NewLine + "from {1} import *";
                    string fullPath = @"C:\Users\gpathak\Documents\new scripts\Automation Scripts (Packet Range)\Document_creator\document creator track to train.py";
                    var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
                    ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();

                // import the module//
                      string scrpitStr = string.Format(importScript, 
        System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath),
                        System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fullPath));
                    var importSrc = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(scrpitStr, Microsoft.Scripting.SourceCodeKind.File);
                    importSrc.Execute(scope);
                    string expr = "functionOfMyModule()";
                    var result = engine.Execute(expr, scope);
            }
            else if (new1.SelectedValue == cbi2)
            {
                Window2 win2 = new Window2();
                win2.Show();
                this.Close();


            }
            else
            {
                Window3 win3 = new Window3();
                win3.Show();
                this.Close();


            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException occurred
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=unexpected token 'creator'
  Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
  StackTrace:`enter code here
   at Microsoft.Scripting.ErrorSink.Add(SourceUnit source, String message, SourceSpan span, Int32 errorCode, Severity severity)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ReportSyntaxError(Token t, SourceSpan span, Int32 errorCode, Boolean allowIncomplete)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFromImportStmt()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSmallStmt()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseSimpleStmt()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseStmt()
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFileWorker(Boolean makeModule, Boolean returnValue)
   at IronPython.Compiler.Parser.ParseFile(Boolean makeModule, Boolean returnValue)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.ParseAndBindAst(CompilerContext context)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompilePythonCode(Nullable`1 compilationMode, SourceUnit sourceUnit, CompilerOptions options, ErrorSink errorSink)
   at IronPython.Runtime.PythonContext.CompileSourceCode(SourceUnit sourceUnit, CompilerOptions options, ErrorSink errorSink)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Compile(CompilerOptions options, ErrorSink errorSink)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.SourceUnit.Execute(Scope scope, ErrorSink errorSink)
   at Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptSource.Execute(ScriptScope scope)
   at Project_new.MainWindow.Welcome_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\gpathak\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\Project new\Project new\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 65
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Project_new.App.Main()
```

This is the error I'm getting. I want to know why this error is coming. I don't have any problem with python script. Its running fine if I run it on `python` IDE but when I try run through `C#` this error is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file name has space change it to underscore, Space is not allowed in import file name.

Your python code is changed to as follows

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\gpathak\Documents\new scripts\Automation Scripts (Packet Range)\Document_creator")
from document creator track to train import *
```

change your `document creator track to train.py` file name to `document_creator_track_to_train.py` and use the same name in your code which will solve the problem.

Comment: Its having this error now...  IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: 'No module named document_creator_track_to_train'

Comment: I m getting this error please help. 
  IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: 'No module named docx'

Comment: Have you installed `docx` package if not please install, For `document_creator_track_to_train` make sure the file name `document_creator_track_to_train.py` exists in the path

Comment: yes i have install docx module in python through pip...but now getting by this code...

Comment: Make sure that your `sys.path` has path to the directory where `docx` is installed (IronPython may not be using same location so you need add that location) You are using two different python installation which is why pip installed package to default folder) you can download and install docx using `ipy setup.py install` instead of `pip install docx`

Comment: yes i m able to run python code by python ide...i installed that by pip already...Its throwing error Microsoft.Scripting.SyntaxErrorException: 'unexpected indent'.   on visual studio